# What do these lines mean as a whole?

Tags: british-english, quotations

I want to know the meaning of these lines as a whole

> Don't worry, even if everything dies around you and it looks like the odds are stacked against you, I will always be with you

And are the sentence structure and grammar correct?

Comment: Please, be more specific and identify what exactly in this sentence you don't understand.

Comment: Also, tell us where you found this sentence. [Here's why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the whole sentence is the last part of it, for it indicates that against all odds that person will always be by your side.

Concerning grammar, I have nothing to correct in these lines. Maybe a dot at the end of the sentence would make it more appealing to a purist, but I am none of them.